# How to get results from web chrome to activity android

Tags: android, kotlin, web, payment

I am working with payment using net banking and doing payment from web chrome now when i back to the activity i want to check that payment is done or cancelled... how to check this in my activity when i came back from web in my android application project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [applinks](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html).

When you have done with payment your backend redirects to custom urls and you can listen them with intent-filters.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

      <data
         android:path="/PaymentCancelled"
         android:host="yourhost.com"
         android:scheme="https" />


      <data
         android:path="/PaymentDone"
         android:host="yourhost.com"
         android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```